# Change MySQL path for "option file" my.ini

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.6

I have upgraded my MySQL Server to 5.6 from 5.0.

Everything works great besides the option file.

When I try, via Workbench 6.1, to create a new my.ini file the system says that it cannot create a my.ini file under Program Files/MySQL/MySQL Server 5.0

I have uninstalled the 5.0 and now I want to tell the system to work on 5.6 folder.

When going into the "Administration - Server Status" page I can see that everything there is defined as the 5.6 folder.

What should I do?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Figured it out.
I needed to Edit the connection in the MySQL Workbench (by right clicking it), then go to the third tab and set the path of that connection to the desired file.

Windows users:
I believe you need to restart the MySQL (or MySQL56) Service in the Windows Services for that to take effect. (also if needed, you can specify the execution path to this file in the service on registry keys)

Comment: I'm also facing the same error in Windows. Even after restarting the MySQL56 and specifying the execution path.It still showing the same error.Not getting connected to MySQL56.

Comment: I finally able to fix this issue. I'm using Windows-10 in that I had to delete the Previously installed MySQl5.1 inside C:\Program Files & **C:\Program Data** which was hidden.(Before that stop the server using Services.msc ).  And installed  MySQL56. Now it's getting connected to new MySQL56.